# SQL: Aggregation of string values from diffrent rows in a mulit-leveled JOIN

Tags: sql, join, string-agg

I have a multi-leveled table hierarchy in SQL Server, and when joining them I want to do an aggregation of strings from rows of one of the tables. In my (simplified) example in the screenshot below, I have Level1->Level2->Level3 and also a table PerformingUser "hanging under" Level1.
I have done a JOIN on all these four tables, resulting in 8 rows. So far all is fine.

Now, what I want is that each of this 8 rows gets a new column ("AllUsersForLevel1") with an aggregation of all PerformingUsers for *its Level1*.
(The intent is that the PerformingUser also can see what other PerformingUsers have the same Level1.)

So for the first 2 rows I want a new column with 'aretha, mary'. And in the other 6 rows that column should have 'john, jim'.

I have tried STRING_AGG (as indicated in the comment in the image), but it requires a grouping (which I do not want; I want all 8 rows).
I also tried to do a STRING_AGG on a OVER (PARTITION BY Level1ID), but got "The function 'STRING_AGG' is not a valid windowing function, and cannot be used with the OVER clause."

Does anyone have advice on how to do this?

[image: Screenshot from SSMS]

Comment: Look at this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b97154d88c642fdc061abab890038326). It's for Oracle, but should help.

Comment: @PonderStibbons: Looks like I cannot mark a commen as accepted answer. If you add an answers, I'll mark it as accepted :-)

Comment: My solution was for Oracle, I only suggested subquery. Post your code as answer and accept it if you want.